# SQL - Compare 2 different ranges of date

Tags: sql, oracle

The table has these columns:

DATA, CODE and so on..

I need to display two different ranges of date and its code like:

|data|code|data2|code|

My query is:

```
SELECT DATA,CODE
FROM people
WHERE DATA >= ${data1} AND DATA <= ${data2}
GROUP BY DATA
ORDER BY DATA
```

What I did was trying to do 2 queries with differents variable but both return always the same range of data.
So I did something like:

```
SELECT DATA,CODE
FROM people
WHERE DATA >= ${d1} AND DATA <= ${d2}
GROUP BY DATA
ORDER BY DATA
```

and try to assign 4 differents date in order to get 2 ranges of period. Let's imagine `data1='01-01-2001'` and `data2='31-12-2001'` while `d1='01-01-2002'` and `d2='31-12-2002'`. 
When I assigned the dates, both return only the last range.

So instead of getting **|2001|code|2002|code|** I've got **|2002|code|2002|code|**
I need for comparison, so I want to compare every day of the year 2001 on the left and with every day of the year 2002 on the right.

Comment: Please read [ask]. add the table's structure, sample data and desired results.

Comment: your query does not match the column names ...

Comment: Consider this oracle RDBMS SQL syntax: `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE (mydatefield BETWEEN TO_DATE('2016-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE('2016-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: Yes. This work for me when I need just one range. But in this case what I want to display are 2 different ranges. I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the bind variables `:start1` and `:end1` as the bounds for the first range and `:start2` and `:end2` as the bounds for the second range:

```
SELECT d1.data AS data1,
       d1.code AS code1,
       d2.data AS data2,
       d2.code AS code2
FROM   (
  SELECT data,
         code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY data ) AS rn
  FROM   people
  WHERE  data BETWEEN :start1 AND :end1
) d1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT data,
         code,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY data ) AS rn
  FROM   people
  WHERE  data BETWEEN :start2 AND :end2
) d2
ON ( d1.rn = d2.rn )
```